# Use Azure Data Lake as GeoServer storage

Tags: geoserver, azure

I've developed an application involving a GeoServer (2.17) instance deployed on an on-premise web server. The data consists of mosaics of GeoTIFF images stored on the web server file system.

Now I need to port the architecture on Azure platform. I need to persist my raster files on an Azure Data Lake Gen2 instance. I know that there are many possible solutions for the GeoServer deployment on Azure (VM, container, AppService, etc), but I can't find a way to connect GeoServer to the storage.

I think I can set up a virtual machine using Azure services to deploy GeoServer and duplicate raster files on the VM's file system but I'd like to connect Geoserver to Azure Data Lake directly.

I found that it is possible to read files from [Amazon S3 buckets](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html), but I didn't find a similar solution for Azure.
I also found [this solution](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Geotiff-hosted-Azure-Blob-Storage-to-be-used-as-mosaic-td5407706.html) but it works with Azure Blob Storage that is different from Azure Data Lake.

Answer (score 1):

This [plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/gwc-azure-blob/index.html) supports the use of the Azure Blob storage as storage medium for GeoWebCache settings. Azure Datalake Gen 2 is built on top of Azure Blob so this should work.  I haven't done any Geoserver work since 2014...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've never used GeoWebCache or BlobStores in my application but I think I need to use Azure Data Lake as the Geoserver data directory. Are the two concepts related?

Comment: GeoWebCache is a tiling service but I imagine it can host your raster files.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently (May 2020) any GeoServer plugin to allow access to data stored on Azure, either in the blob store or the lake. Such a plugin could be written based on either the older [S3 code](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html) or the newer [COG plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/community/cog/index.html).

If you are unable to develop the code with your own resources there are [commercial companies](http://geoserver.org/support/) that can. (Disclaimer, I work for one of those companies.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The S3 plugin works only with single raster files or with ImageMosaics too?